# Можно ли поменять fill у SVG заданого файлом в фоновом изображении?

Tags: php, css, svg

На серверной стороне есть данные:

```
$arr[0]['title'] = 'John Smith';
$arr[0]['photo'] = 'img/John Smith.svg';
```

Из этих данных вычисляется цвет иконки персонажа:

```
$color = '#'.mb_substr(md5($arr[0]['title']),0,3);
```

Из этих данных формируется код:

```
<style>
.pic {
  background-image: url(".$arr[0]['photo'].");
  fill: ".$color.";
}
</style>

<h2>".$arr[0]['title']."</h2>
<div class="pic">
</div>
```

Не было бы проблемы, если бы SVG картинка была добавлена в HTML инлайн или Base64.
Но как окрасить ее, когда она задана в файле?

**UPD:** Казалось бы элегантное решение прописать в css `.pic {--svg-color: ".$color."}` и `style="fill: var(--svg-color)"` внутри svg файла, но не работает, когда картинка - это фон. (

**UPD2:** По многочисленным просьбам добавил картинку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: filter hue rotate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если SVG иконка добавлена отдельным файлом с помощью тега `<img>`, то это тоже самое, как добавить растровое изображение,  к которому невозможно применить изменение цвета с помощью CSS правил. Возможно только поменять цвет `background`.

**Но есть способ сделать изменение цвета иконки с помощью фильтров `CSS` или `SVG`**

Допустим добавлена иконка ключа с помощью `<img>`:

```css
img 
{
width:100px;
height:100px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://twemoji.maxcdn.com/svg/1f511.svg">
```

С помощью различных css фильтров меняем цвет иконок:

```css
.container {
display:inline-block;
width:25%;
height:25%;
padding:1.5em;
background: rgb(123,215,193);
background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(123,215,193,1) 4%, rgba(225,233,148,1) 97%);
}
.key {
  height: 3em;
  width: 3em;
 
   }
.grey-out {
  opacity: 0.4;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
}
.hue-rotate {
    -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(90deg);
    filter: hue-rotate(90deg);
}
.invert {
  
  -webkit-filter: invert(100%);
  filter: invert(100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<img class="key" src="https://twemoji.maxcdn.com/svg/1f511.svg"> 
  <img class="key grey-out" src="https://twemoji.maxcdn.com/svg/1f511.svg"> 
   <img class="key hue-rotate" src="https://twemoji.maxcdn.com/svg/1f511.svg"> 
    <img class="key invert" src="https://twemoji.maxcdn.com/svg/1f511.svg">
</div>
```

**Пример, если svg файл добавлен с помощью background-image:**

```css
.key {
  background-image: url("https://twemoji.maxcdn.com/svg/1f506.svg");
  display: inline-block;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  height: 3em;
  width: 3em;
  margin: 0 0.15em 0 0.3em;
  vertical-align: -0.3em;
  background-size: 3em 3em; 
 }
.grey-out {
  opacity: 0.4;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
}
.hue-rotate {
    -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(90deg);
    filter: hue-rotate(90deg);
}
.invert {
   -webkit-filter: invert(100%);
    filter: invert(100%);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="key"></span>
  <span class="key grey-out"></span>
  <span class="key hue-rotate"></span>
  <span class="key invert"></span>
</div>
```

**Вариант с изменением цвета при наведении**

```css
.container {
display: -webkit-flex; 
display: flex; 
width:35%;
height:35%;
}
.key {
  height: 3em;
  width: 3em;
   padding: 1em;
   transition:  0.8s;
   }
:hover.key{
  height: 4em;
  width: 4em;
    -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(320deg);
     filter: hue-rotate(320deg);
   }
.grey-out {
  opacity: 0.4;
   -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
}
.hue-rotate {
    -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(90deg);
    filter: hue-rotate(90deg);

  
}
.invert {
    -webkit-filter: invert(100%);
    filter: invert(100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<img class="key" src="https://twemoji.maxcdn.com/svg/1f511.svg"> 
  <img class="key grey-out" src="https://twemoji.maxcdn.com/svg/1f511.svg"> 
   <img class="key hue-rotate" src="https://twemoji.maxcdn.com/svg/1f511.svg"> 
    <img class="key invert" src="https://twemoji.maxcdn.com/svg/1f511.svg">
</div>
```

Comment: Если в лоб применять ваше решение - то работать не будет. Для начала нужно задать в svg-файле цвет. Потом, к счастью цвет в который нужно покрасить svg значения не имеет, главное чтобы всегда был одним и тем же для одной и той же персоны. Можно взять из md5 2 символа и привести их в угол для hue-rotate. В принципе да, можно принять как ответ.

Comment: @AndreyFedorov мой конёк SVG, но не php. Поэтому решил помочь в той сфере, которую знаю. Если вы дальше знаете, как это можно автоматизировать, то всё уже хорошо. Могу показать варианты, как перекрасить иконку с SVG фильтрами

Comment: @Alexandr_TT цвет ключа свойством filter можно менять на любой ?

Comment: @Leks Да, только надо подобрать угол `filter: hue-rotate(320deg);`

Comment: @Alexandr_TT ок спасибо

Comment: @Alexandr_TT  цвет ключа можно сделать виде градиента ?

Answer (score 0):

А что вам мешает использовать инлайновые стили, и красить вашей $color уже получаемый html фаил ? Что то по типу `<div class="pic"><svg ... fill=".$color."></svg></div>`

Comment: Вы не поняли. Там нет `<div class="pic"><svg ... fill=".$color.">...`. svg - это фон div'а.

Comment: Эммм, а так пробовали .pic { background: ".$color." url(".$arr[0]['photo'].") 50% 50% no-repeat;}  ?

Comment: оно красит фон svg, а мне нужно наоборот, саму svg покрасить, но мысль интересная.

Comment: Я так до конца и не понял, что во что красить) Если бы к вопросу были приделаны картинки, это бы сильно облегчило понимание. Ну и ещё есть css свойство inherit которое возможно поможет вам вызывать цвет в зависимости от родителя

Comment: Добавил картинку